# бесплатная встроенная СУБД .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, entity-framework

подскажите бесплатную ВСТРОЕННУЮ СУБД (чтобы шла с моим приложением и не требовала отдельной установки), работающую на Net 3.5, поддерживающую Entity Framework, LINQ, хранимые процедуры и представления, и имеющую удобную систему обновления схемы данных. Я рассмотрел SQL Server Compact, но там нет поддержки хранимых процедур, SQL Lite не работает с EF, SQL server LocalDB не является встраиваемой как я понял. И вроде как FireBird удовлетворяет всем требованиям, но не могу найти как можно обновлять схему данных. А вообще задача стоит найти замену для SQL Server Express, который используется в моем приложении сейчас, и который приходится устанавливать на машину клиентов.

Comment: *SQLite не работает с EF* -- [да ну](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.EF6)?

Comment: Да, с этим по ходу ошибся. Но поддержки хранимых процедур нет все равно. http://habrahabr.ru/post/149356/

Comment: Честно говоря, я не вижу смысла в хранимых процедурах для **встраиваемой** базы, но дело ваше. Я пользовался Firebird под линуксами и плююсь до сих пор, а о других подходящих СУБД не слышал.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, используйте [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/index.html). `EF v >= 6.0` поддерживает работу с SQLite, использовал в своих проектах, никаких проблем не возникло. Кроме одной, то, что `EF` не умеет создавать сам таблицы в технологии `CodeFirst`, но это решается(если нужно, добавлю в ответ).

Что касается хранимых процедур, то [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172735/create-use-user-defined-functions-in-system-data-sqlite) есть пример создания функций(не совсем хранимая процедура, но все таки), которую вы можете использовать в своих запросах, посмотрите пример